# Connect to Azure MySQL Database using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, azure, mysql-workbench

I have a Web App running on Azure. I can connect to the DB with Visual Studio and sending/retrieving data on my app works fine.

However, I can not connect to the MySQL db using MySQL Workbench.
The error that I have is

`Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 54`

I have whitelisted my IP on the azure portal and opened the port 1433 on my computer. I don't understand why can't I connect using MySQL Workbench while having no problem with Visual Studio.

**EDIT:**

Here is how i have setup MySQL Workbench:

[image: MySQL Workbench]

And Here is my Azure portal:

[image: Azure Portal]

I'm using port 1433 because that is the port given on the Azure Portal, but also in this tutorial: [Connect to Azure DB using MySQL Workbench](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-hNncIsjyQ)

Comment: Have you mixed up MySQL with SQL Server? 1433 is the port on which SQL Server listens. MySQL uses a different port. And there is no "Azure MySQL" product. Azure SQL is a SQL Server database. In any case, It *doesn't* matter which port you open on your machine, it's the *server's* port you want to connect to. For Azure SQL there are tutorials that show you how to connect securely.

Comment: Microsoft has kind of embraced open source and apparently offers [MySQL databases in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/). Of course, MySQL default port is 3306 and I can't tell whether they allow remote access.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you configured your connection in MySQL Workbench (of course, please don't include your real server name, username, or password). Note: All needed information for connecting is provided within the Settings->Properties blade for ClearDB-based MySQL databases (where you'll need hostname, port, username, and password).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Done, I have added my settings.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that when I go on `Settings -> Properties -> Show database connection strings`, It doesn't give me any random User/Password like it does in several tutorials I've seen. It just gives me my username (Which I use on the Server) and for the `password` field, it just says `Your password here`. The password should be generated if I'm not wrong...

Comment: @Dliix - that's because your database isn't MySQL - it's SQL Database. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok - now that you included screenshots: You're trying to use MySQL Workbench to connect to a SQL Database (which is SQL Server as a service, not MySQL).

Edit: 8/15/2017
Azure now offers [Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/) which is currently in public preview.

In your specific case, you created a SQL Database, which cannot be manipulated with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Alright, I got it thanks ! Do you have any software that I could use to manage my DB other than Visual Studio then ? Because VS is actually very slow... Thanks again !

Comment: A quick google search of "SQL Server Management Tools" will enlighten you :)